# Java Netty data break

Tags: java, netty

I am using in my project netty-3.5.3.Final to transfer files. Unfortunately, sometimes I get the wrong data. For example, I am downloading a file size of 1 GB. After receiving the file contains 5 "mistakes". All errors affect the individual bytes. This is a "logical" change[image]

```
Ë -> ë  (CB -> EB)  C+2 = E
À -> à  (C0 -> E0)  C+2 = E
Ú -> ú  (DA -> FA)  D+2 = F
œ -> ¼  (9C -> BC)  9+2 = B
 -> $   (04 -> 24)  0+2 = 2
e.t.c.
(Not every Ë becomes ë, only ~1/100000000...000..)
```

The process of obtaining the file:

```
ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage(); //SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(...)..
 ByteBuffer bbuf = buf.toByteBuffer();
RandomAccessFile bos = new RandomAccessFile(...,"rw");
bos.write(bbuf.array(), 0, bbuf.position());
bos.close();
```

Data are not subject to any changes. Why can it happen?

Comment: Do you know what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your write code is wrong.

Could you try this:

```
ChannelBuffer buf = ...
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(...)
buf.readBytes(out, buf.readableBytes());
out.close();
```